# Using wget to download directories over FTP, but not passing the password as a parameter

Tags: security, bash, ftp, passwords, wget

When I don't have SSH access to a server, I usually download stuff over FTP, like this:

```
wget -r ftp://user:pass@server/path/to/dir
```

How do I keep my password more secure? I don't like that the password is in the command, but when I try something like this:

```
wget -r ftp://user@server/path/to/dir
```

it doesn't work. It gives me "Login incorrect".

Comment: secure from what? What's the attack scenario you're trying to prevent?

Comment: @yan, It's not secure to pass passwords in commands. It shows up in my bash history, my scripts, etc. Plus, if I want to change it, I'd like to have it in one place.

Comment: Using ftp is not "secure", you're not defining what "secure" means to you. Do you want to enter it every time? Are you afraid of .bash_history caching it? Is it on a shared machine?

Comment: @yan, If I want to change it, I'd like to have it in one place. And it's nice to have less to type.

Comment: read section 5.5 from http://wget.addictivecode.org/FrequentlyAskedQuestions?action=show&redirect=Faq#Is_there_a_way_to_hide_my_clear-text_user.2BAC8-pass_combo_from_the_process_table.3F

Comment: @yan, http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#URL-Format Look for "Important Note".

Comment: About security, the question is whether it is more probable for an attacker to listen to your FTP connection (and there get your password in clear), or to be logged in at the same time at the same computer (and there get the password from the command line when viewing `ps` or similar). I can think about both scenarios now ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put your credentials in [`~/.wgetrc`](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Wgetrc-Commands.html) like so:

```
ftp_user = user
ftp_password = pass
```

Depending on your needs, it is also possible to [use a different location](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Wgetrc-Location.html) for this configuration file:

> When initializing, Wget will look for a global startup file, /usr/local/etc/wgetrc by default (or some prefix other than /usr/local, if Wget was not installed there) and read commands from there, if it exists.
>
> Then it will look for the user's file. If the environmental variable WGETRC is set, Wget will try to load that file. Failing that, no further attempts will be made.
>
> If WGETRC is not set, Wget will try to load $HOME/.wgetrc.

Answer (score 8):

This also does the trick:

```
wget -r --ask-password ftp://user@server/path/to/dir
```

[`ask_password = on/off`](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Wgetrc-Commands.html) can also be declared in your `~/.wgetrc`.