# downloading file from ftp server via wget fails

Tags: linux, ftp, wget

I am downloading a file from an FTP server using wget. If I type in

```
ftp://username:password@datatransfer.cj.com/some_path/file
```

into my browser, the file is downloaded fine.

If I instead do,

```
wget ftp://username:password@datatransfer.cj.com/some_path/file -O /path/file.txt
```

It says login incorrect.

What are some possible reasons this may occur and how can I fix it.

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5277991/using-wget-to-download-directories-over-ftp-but-not-passing-the-password-as-a-p posting. It should solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out you need to hex encode special characters in the password if sending the request with wget.

I found this from the following page:

https://www.smartftp.com/support/kb/url-that-contains-in-password-f187.html